# disabling play/pause in embedded video using JW player

Tags: javascript, jwplayer, video-embedding

I am using JW (v 5.8) player to embed a video. And I want to do it so that autostart is enabled, allowing the video to start playing as soon as the page loads, the controlbar is disabled so that a viewer cannot seek to a random point in a video and the play/pause function on clicking the video is disabled. To embed the mp4 video, I am using JW player.
I managed to accomplish the first 2 tasks, but to disable the play/pause function on clicking the screen, I am trying to use the clickproxy plugin and it does not work. I am pasting my code below:

```
<div id="mediaplayer">JW Player goes here</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jwplayer.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jwplayer('mediaplayer').setup({
        'flashplayer': 'player.swf',
        'file': 'video.mp4',
        'controlbar': 'none',
        'width': '1000',
        'height': '1000',
        'plugins': 'clickproxy',
        'clickproxy.listener': 'clickListener',
        'autostart': 'true'
    });
function clickListener(obj)
{
}
</script>
```

Right now with this code, the video loads, but doesn't even start playing, and clicking on the video doesn't do anything because of the clickproxy plugin. Anyway to accomplish what I want?
I am a newbie in javascript, so any help will be really appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ahhh yes, there used to be functionality in the player to do this (about ignoring the click) but it seems it keeps getting removed.

Here's the solution I've just implemented that works for me, I simply plug into the onPause javascript event and start the media playing again.

```
    <script type='text/javascript'>
  jwplayer('mediaspace').setup({
    'flashplayer': '/jw/player.swf',
    'file': 'http://d3usowdy51yate.cloudfront.net/your-mp4-goes-here.mp4',
    'autostart': 'true',
    'icons': 'true',
    'stretching': 'fill',
    'controlbar': 'none',
    'width': '640',
    'height': '360',
    events: {
        onPause: function(event) {
          jwplayer('mediaspace').play();}
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Yes I agree this is not nice - but neither is removing the ability to disable the click!  I've paid for the player, part of the point should be that I can control how it plays :-).

Answer (score 3):

You can use the CSS property pointer-events on the `#mediaplayer` to prevent the click event to go trough to the video:

```
#mediaplayer {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

You could also abuse the `onPause` event as a fallback for older browsers `<IE9`, by saying; play the video if the pause event is executed:

```
jwplayer('mediaplayer').setup({
    flashplayer: 'player.swf',
    file: 'video.mp4',
    controlbar: 'none',
    width: '1000',
    height: '1000',
    autostart: 'true',
    events: {
        onPause: function() {
            this.play(true);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: ok @Sindre Sorhus , `#mediaplayer {
    pointer-events: none;
}` this works fine, but what if i want to prevent the click to go through the video and at the same time to be able to click the controlbar only?

Comment: Then you need to apply the `pointer-events: none` to a deeper layer not including the controlbar.

Comment: and how is it? we're talking about a flash object, right? so inside the `<div id="mediaplayer">JW Player goes here</div>` it is created the `<object ...>` containing `<param ...>`, so beneath the mediaplayer div there's not so much to apply css. or am i losing something?

Comment: You need to wrap the `<object>` in a `<div>` and apply the pointer-events there.

Answer (score 2):

Try to put a transparent div over the player with the same dimension of the player.

Comment: I am not sure how that would help... also, could you please show some source code as to how you would approach this? As I said I am a complete newbie to web programming and JS. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks for the idea TheWiseJah. Worked perfectly for my needs.

Comment: create a div - transparent or maybe 50% opacity, with style position:absolute, width:100%, height:100%, z-index: 10 and then do $(jwplayer().container).append(div)