# How to disable play | pause on display on Jwplayer?

Tags: javascript, xml, jwplayer, skinning

i know there was already a similar question to this, but the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8829328/disabling-play-pause-in-embedded-video-using-jw-player) is not enough for me.
question is the following: i've a jwplayer with skin (i'm using jwplayer 5 and not 6, because skinning with xml is not working properly, but the same configurations works perfectly with the 5)

this player has some needs

- the only one button on the controlbar should be the Fullscreen (it works)
- the position of the controlbar should be on top (i was not able to find the xml configuration to do that, only to position it on left or right, always on bottom)
- the play / pause operation on the display should be removed (i was not able to find the xml configuration to do that)
- the rotating buffering icon while buffering on the display (it works)

i don't copy the jwplayer setup, because it's the basic one

are there some solutions?

Comment: Which player version are you using here? 5 or 6?

Comment: Okay, you can set the controlbar variable to top in jw5, and set the icons variable to false, that should work. http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/jw-player-for-flash-v5/12536/configuration-options